# How to show mysql records more than once and in a specific order

Tags: php, mysql, sql

1) This is a much simplified example of what I am trying to do for ease of explaining the problem. 2) I will be doing thousands of these queries.

I have a mysql table like so:

```
NUMBER   TEXTCOLOUR
one      green
two      red
three    orange
four     pink
```

I want to display the following (each word having a different textcolour), in this order:

> three two one three

I have tried:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `number` IN ('three', 'two', 'one','three') 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(number, 'three,two,one,three')";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "
<div class='" .$textcolour. "'>$number</div>
";
}
```

but this will not display the record 'three' more than once. Also I don't want to have to write the same array twice (once for IN and again for the ORDER BY) as I have to write thousands of these queries.

So the question: How to show mysql records **more than once** and in a **specific order** with the **least amount** of code?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `SELECT` will never return the same row more than once, unless you use `UNION ALL` to collect results from multiple queries.

Comment: The initial sequence, `three`, `two`, `one`, `three`, do you have that in the database as well?

Comment: Thanks all. @Mogul, no there's no other databases, just the table mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```sql
SELECT b.textcolour
  FROM 
(SELECT 'three' number UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'two' UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'one' UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'three') a LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.number = b.number
```

Output:

```
| TEXTCOLOUR |
--------------
|     orange |
|        red |
|      green |
|     orange |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45667/7)**

You can consider inserting those sequences in some (temp) table with an auto_increment column and a column that designates particular sequence. Then you can just do

```sql
SELECT b.textcolour
  FROM sequences a JOIN colours b
    ON a.number = b.number
 WHERE a.seq_no = ?
 ORDER BY a.id
```

**[SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3788b/1)**

Comment: +1 sorta hackish but indeed it works, and should be super fast too.

Comment: 1st suggestion works perfectly thanks so much! For other's reference here's the php too, it took me a while to figure out I had to use mysql_fetch_object:  `$result = mysql_query("SELECT b.textcolour
  FROM 
(SELECT 'three' number UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'two' UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'one' UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'three') a LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.number = b.number");

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))`  I will bear in mind the temp table. Thanks again @peterm

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @peterm for the answer (with extra php added for others' use)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT b.textcolour FROM (
SELECT 'three' number UNION ALL 
SELECT 'two' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'one' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'three'
) a LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.number = b.number"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
```